# How to write a SQL statement to get the number of concurrent screen views from table

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table:

```
user_id | timestamp.               | post_number
123     | 2022-04-01 17:32:52 UTC  |  1
234     | 2022-04-01 17:35:52 UTC  |  1
546     | 2022-04-01 17:32:52 UTC  |  1
765     | 2022-04-01 18:32:52 UTC  |  1
143     | 2022-04-01 17:32:54 UTC  |  1
123     | 2022-04-01 18:32:52 UTC  |  2
234     | 2022-04-01 18:32:53 UTC  |  2
546     | 2022-04-01 18:40:02 UTC  |  2
```

I want to count the number of users with concurrent screen views (define concurrent as within 2 second of each other) for each post.
My desire output will look like this:

```
post_number | concurrent_screeenviews
1           | 3
2           | 4
```

For a particular timestamp, it will be as simple as a `TIMESTAMPDIFF` but how do I iterate over the entire timestamps in a given day?

I am using MySQL in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try something like this. In the inner query, I've used the [lag](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-lag-function-overview-and-examples/) function to order the timestamp, then the current timestamp with the previous timestamp to see if it's within 2 seconds. However, the 1st timestamp for each post number won't be counted in the inner query, so I've added it in the outer query.

```
SELECT t.postnumber, 1+SUM(t.cnt) as concurrent_screeenviews FROM (
  SELECT postnumber, 
         time_stamp,
         if (time_stamp - LAG(time_stamp) over (partition by postnumber order by time_stamp) <= 2, 1, 0)  as cnt
  FROM table1 
) AS t
group by t.postnumber
```

[db fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/arPWG2shiDxTJjD4cLj8bW/0)